# C++ How to ignore defined method in header file?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, header, annotations, g++

i want a compiler (MinGW g++/Linux g++) to ignore some defined stuff in a header file:

```
class A {
    public:
       A();
       virtual ~A();

    IGNORE void methodA(); // = 0 -> not possible
    IGNORE void methodB(); // = 0 -> not possible
}
```

The problem: methodA() and methodB() can't be pure virtual because the class would be later instanciated, so it gives a compiler error. The reason for doing that: i want to have a readable header file, so this methods should be appear in files - the methods are only used as in the QT framework to work as "signals", which are translated as Strings with a macro.
May be it is possible to declare a macro to let it be as annotation? i saw this in the QT5 framework (declared signal methods) but its not working with my code...
What i not want to do: list the methods only as DOC annotation.

Thanks for a idea how to solve that ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
void methodA(int) = delete; // note: requires C++11
void methodA(double);
```

will cause a compiler error if you ever try to use `methodA(int)`, but not if you're trying to use `methodA(double)`.

Comment: gives variant (a) error if i try to use the method in a macro?

Comment: @AndreasBf If the macro is expanded and results in a function call seen by the compiler, then yes, of course.

Comment: Ok, so i cant write ------#define XYZ(a) ""#a------- with your hint?

Comment: BTW: QT uses annotations for signals: what are doing annotations when compiling? when i use QTs defines, i get a lot of warnings "annotate attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]"

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to ignore methods as described what i want to do:

```
#define IGNORE __attribute__((unused))
#define METHOD_TO_STRING(a) ""#a
```

so i can write in header files

```
class A {
    public:
        IGNORE void methodA();

        void doStuff(const char *stuff);

        void methodB() {
            doStuff(METHOD_TO_STRING(methodA());
        }
};
```

Now the compiler is happy and i can pass methods as args :)
Thanks for the tips